# AmCharts5: How to change the x axis label and tooltip using a DateAxis?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4, amcharts5

With the amcharts4 I do something like this for the change tooltip and label text for the x axis with the CategoryAxis...

```
// change tooltip
this.xAxis.adapter.add("getTooltipText", (text, target) => {
    const value = text ? parseInt(text) : -1;
    return this.getAxisToolTipText(value);
});

// change label
this.xAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", (text, target) => {
    const value = target.dataItem && target.dataItem.category ? parseInt(target.dataItem.category) : -1;
    return this.getAxisText(value, text);
});
```

But now, how to do the same for the Amcharts5 with DateAxis?

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use adapters to dynamically modify setting value of its target element.

#### Axis labels:

```
xAxis.get("renderer").labels.template.adapters.add("html", function(html, target) {
  return "<div style=\"text-align: center; font-weight: bold;\">{value.formatDate('d MMM')}</div><div style=\"text-align: center;\">{value.formatDate('EEE')}</div>";
});
```

See [amCharts5 - Axis labels](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/common-elements/html-content/#Axis_labels)

#### Axis tooltip

```
xAxis.get("tooltip").adapters.add("labelText", function(text, target) {
  return "Custom text";
});
```

[AxisRenderX documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/axisrendererx/)